# How to explicitly specify controller method in Razor form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, form-submit

How can I get finer control over which controller method is called by my Razor form submit?

My controller has two methods:

```
public ActionResult ControllerMethod()
{
    MyModel savedModel = GetSaveModelFromSomewhere();
    // do some specific stuff here...
    return ControllerMethod(savedModel);
}

public ActionResult ControllerMethod(MyModel model)
{
    // do some general stuff here...
}
```

My view contains:

```
@Model MyModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("ControllerMethod", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
        <input id="Submit" type="submit" value="Update Profile" class="btn" />
}
```

I presume that because the view is using `MyModel` the framework automatically calls `ControllerMethod(MyModel)` but how can I explicitly get it to call the first `ControllerMethod()`?

I can achieve this by decorating `ControllerMethod()` with `[AcceptVerbs("GET")]` and using `FormMethod.Get` in the view, but that just seems like a workaround to me.

Comment: Don't fight the conventions. They're there for a reason.

Comment: I'm confused by the pattern you're using. Can you explain why one method is calling anther? The Post should be able to post the model directly as the parm of the post method because of Model Binding.

Comment: Overall what I'm trying to achieve is to make the model available to  the view for display purposes, but I then want a button that will move me on to another action without submitting that model. I guess in this case I should be calling the controller action via AJAX or some other mechanism; `submit` just seemed to be a 'simpler' way to do this. As for methods calling another, I was just trying to leverage existing functionality instead of moving shared code out into separate functions, but I can see why this is not a good thing. I'm still a relative newbie, but this alone has taught me lots!

Comment: @GaryChapman, All you need is a link which you can generate with `@Html.AtionLink("Display text", "SomeOtherMethod", "Home")`. [Refer docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

You may be confused about the the way this works. You typically have a GET and a POST method for each action where you need to create or edit data. The GET method initializes your model and returns it to the view for editing in a form

```
[HttpGet] // this is the default and is not strictly required
public ActionResult ControllerMethod()
{
  MyModel model = GetSaveModelFromSomewhere();
  return View(model);
}
```

which you would call with `/Home/ControllerMethod`, and the view

```
@Model MyModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  // render controls for your model
  <input id="Submit" type="submit" value="Update Profile" class="btn" />
}
```

and the POST method

```
[HttpPost] // this attribute distinguishes the POST method from the GET method
public ActionResult ControllerMethod(MyModel model)
{
  if(!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return View(model); // return the view to correct errors
  }
  // Save the model and redirect to somewhere else.
  RedirectToAction("SomeOtherMethod");
}
```

You can only have one POST method for the same signature. If you want to post back to another method, say

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AnotherMethod(MyModel model)
```

then in the view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AnotherMethod", "Home"))
```

Comment: Using GET was just a workaround to allow me to call the method I wanted to, which I see now is not the best way to do it. Thanks for your input - things are making a lot more sense to me now.

Answer (score 1):

You can decorate your post method with `[HttpPost]`.

Comment: I just tried that and now it's throwing an exception because of ambiguity between the two method names. I think renaming may be the best solution :-)

Comment: You shouldn't need to, though. The method names are the same, but if one is decorated with HttpPost then it should know which to use when.

Answer (score 1):

The fact of the matter is, you aren't doing yourself any favors by nesting the call to what is supposed to be your POST method inside of your GET method. If you just post back to the correct method, there won't be any issues.

```
// This is the GET method. It should return your model in the view.
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    MyModel savedModel = GetSaveModelFromSomewhere();
    // do some specific stuff here...
    return View(savedModel);
}

// This is the POST method. It now accepts your model back from the POST.
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyModel model)
{
    // do some general stuff here...

    if (success)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        // Show the view again if saving the edits failed for any reason.
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

You can always wrap any shared code into a 3rd method or a shared service if that is what you are trying to achieve by nesting your action calls.

Comment: Yep I'm trying to leverage existing code, but I think a 3rd method is the way to go. I just thought I'd try to keep things simple (ha).